# Dukascopy historical data per-tick, bid and ask volume?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-valuation, trading-volume

I am using [Dukascopy's historical data](https://www.dukascopy.com/trading-tools/widgets/quotes/historical_data_feed). I am using a candlestick of 1 tick, volume units of "units," and chose TSLA data.

Here is an example of the data:

[image: stock data]

As you can see, the bid and ask volume are the same, and are same throughout all time: constant at 1200.0001. What is this number, and why is it useful? Is this a bug of some sort?